# Generating and linking to multiple prawn pdfs single action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn

I'm currently generating a PDF using the Prawn gem on my `show` action:

```
format.pdf do
  pdf = ProcurementReportPdf.new @real_property_sale_project, current_user, view_context
  send_data pdf.render,
  filename: "ProcurementReport.pdf",
  type: "application/pdf",
  disposition: "inline"
end
```

I access the pdf in my show view like so:

```
<%= link_to '', "/real_property_sale_projects/#{@rpsp.id}.pdf", class: "fa fa-file-pdf-o right track-with-mixpanel", :data => { :event => "clicked bid export icon", tooltip: "export_bids" }, :title => "Procurement Report (PDF)", :target => "_blank" %>
# this line is for the scroll bar, so you can read the code
```

I would like to generate a second report for this action but I'm unsure of the best way to do this? After generating the report how would I go about linking to it in my view?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by defining the following method in the controller:

```
 def vendor_report
    @real_property_sale_project = RealPropertySaleProject.find params[:project_id]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        vendor_report = VendorReportPdf.new @real_property_sale_project, current_user, view_context
        send_data vendor_report.render,
          filename: "Vendor_Report.pdf",
          type: "application/pdf",
          disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
  end
```

Added a route:

```
get 'vendor_report', to: 'real_property_sale_projects#vendor_report', as: 'vendor_report'
```

And then added the link in the `show` view:

`<%= link_to 'vendor report', vendor_report_path(project_id: @rpsp.id, format: 'pdf') %>`